# Confusion about restoration of parenthesis.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

In "Introduction to Mathematical Logic" by Elliot Mendelson , page $11-12$ , There is a passage about the restoration of parenthesis . As a example:

$1. B \rightarrow \lnot\lnot A$ 
$2. B \rightarrow \lnot(\lnot A)$ 
$3. B \rightarrow (\lnot(\lnot A))$ 
$4. (B \rightarrow (\lnot(\lnot A)))$

But in the passage they said: *"Find the **leftmost**
occurrence of the strongest connective that has not yet been processed."*

And in the $2nd$ line , They didn't restore the **leftmost** negation.This is were I am confused.Is there something wrong with my reasoning?Because I thought It will be something like this:-

$1. B \rightarrow \lnot\lnot A$ 
$2. B \rightarrow (\lnot\lnot A)$ 
$3. B \rightarrow (\lnot(\lnot A))$ 
$4. (B \rightarrow (\lnot(\lnot A)))$

Another confusing example (for me) :

$1. A ∨ \lnot(B \rightarrow A ∨ B)$ 
$2. A ∨ \lnot(B \rightarrow (A ∨ B))$ 
$3. A ∨ (\lnot(B \rightarrow (A ∨ B)))$ 
$4. (A ∨ (\lnot(B \rightarrow (A ∨ B))))$

On the $2nd$ line , $\lnot$ is the strongest connective , but they choose $\lor$ first for restoration.

Comment: Maybe a typo...

Comment: I don't know for sure if it is a typo or not.I kind of want other peoples opinions too on this because I did not find any other write-ups about restoration of parenthesis on the internet.Maybe it is not even a typo and I am the one who is being dumb.

Comment: For a correct set of rule, see [Enderton](https://books.google.it/books?id=dVncCl_EtUkC&pg=PA33), page 33.